# Restful service layer with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I need a advice on creating a architecture where i want API layer in between UI layer and Business Layer. UI layer should only consume rest services for displaying data.

Reason for doing this is that we need to expose same service for others clients like Ipad, Android etc.

Now my question is:-

1) Do we need dependence inject in this case? (i don't think so coz we are not going to use any reference at UI layer. The only thing is, we are manipulating the JSON returning by service.)

2) Will it hurt performance?

3) Is this the right approach?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you should add webapi tag too for webapi experts to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we're doing roughly the same thing now.

**1)** No, you can't.

**2)** No, twitter is api first, they seem to be doing ok. I guess technically it will, but it does mean you can scale horizontally so the extra hop overhead can easily be counteracted.

**3)** You have multiple ui clients so it seems like a decent viable solution.

**Security**
Security:  Basic Authentication
Its the easiest to setup, but be aware the token is reversible, so use HTTPS to encrypt the communication. 
The HTTP Authorization header containing the username and password is sent with every request to the api level.

You could use session but that requires a bit more setup.

There are plenty of how to's on setting up basic authenication in C# and web api.

Comment: and what about API security? @Choco Smith

Comment: @AmitSoni added security section. i'd probably just use basic authentication header. we use it but we also have https for all our communication.

Answer (score 1):

The way i created an API for me was:

- Project 1 : WebAPI serving as a portal to fetch data
- Project 2 : Class Library, providing services to the WebAPI layer.
- Project 3 : Class Library, providing data to my services layer using EF.

Now, different controllers in the web api project require different service objects(from project 2) to work with. I had to provide constructors for those controllers using DI. for this i used Autofac.

For you, your business layer would be Project 2.

Data flowing through one more Project layer might take some time, and you will need to put up exception handling and logging again in the API layer. i don't think performance should be big problem here.

Comment: if you go with WEBApi, then how will other clients use the same framework?

Comment: WebAPI focuses on creating a RESTful API. Clients like Ipad, Android do work with HTTP request and response. For them our API is just like another HTTP request. It doesn't matter to them on what platform was the API created as long as we can serve the content they need. Did i understand your question? is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: My question is:- if we use WEBAPI then, how will other clients uses the system?
i.e. IOS/Android.

Coz Web API will not work as separate layer.

Comment: OR you are saying to create a separate layer of WEBAPI?

Comment: yes a separate layer of web api. as a different project. this will be the one endpoint all clients will interact with.

Comment: your existing UI layer is just another client like those IOS/Androids.

Comment: Right, that's make sense. And what about security?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92006/discussion-between-singsuyash-and-amit-soni).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I've seen such platform oriented approach - providing [mSOA](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) to *N* amount of clients. The architectural solution was a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) that was hiding all the complex Business Layer requests and in the same time providing UI insensitive processing.

> Will it hurt performance?

Not necessary - since it has knowledge of how to handle all required sub-systems requests. All the clients just know that they need a single JSON contract to get the job done, not which and how many of the services to call. By doing so - we have a much better and simplified communication. Take a look at the [Mediation (intra-communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration) pattern:

[image: Mediator]